# getting the input from a textfield outside of the textfield environment

Tags: forms, textfield

Hi i want to do the following thing: Check if a textfield has an input.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt, hidelinks]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{makecell,
  tabularx}           
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


%\begin{document}


%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
    \TextField[width=5cm,name= test]{}\\
        \TextField[width=5cm,name= testt]{}\\
 
 %event.value=this.getField('test').value

\def\mymacroA{getField('test').value}
\def\mymacroB{}
\def\mymacroC{E}
\def\mymacroD{ E }


\ifdefempty{\mymacroA}{YES}{NO}\par
\ifdefempty{\mymacroB}{YES}{NO}\par
\ifdefempty{\mymacroC}{YES}{NO}\par
\ifdefempty{\mymacroD}{YES}{NO}
        
\end{Form}

% \pdfstrcmp {text1}{text2} evaluates to 0 if text1 and text2 are equal
% to -1 if text1 comes first in lexicographic order, to +1 else
% To test if the strings are equal we thus use not(\pdfstrcmp {text1}{text2})
% (or we can use the ! as synonym of the "not" function)

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't do that outside a field, also the field is never set when you compile the latex code but when you open the pdf so it doesn't make sense to try to retrieve the value during the compilation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you know how to check if the TextField has an input in the pdf?

Comment: add another (if you want hidden) field with javascript code.